# Qual è il significato di "indentatura" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Tutto un trucco della mente: nella stanza, tranne Gennaro, nel lettino accanto, col suo respiro regolare, non c’erano persone e suoni veri. Ma questo non la calmò, anzi moltiplicò lo spavento. I battiti del cuore erano ormai così potenti che parevano capaci di far saltare l’**indentatura** delle cose. La tenacia del morso che serrava tra loro le pareti della stanza si indeboliva, quegli urti violenti nella gola scuotevano il letto, aprivano crepe nell’intonaco, le dissaldavano la calotta cranica, forse avrebbero rotto il bambino, sì, lo avrebbero rotto come un pupazzo di celluloide, spaccandolo in petto e nella pancia e nella testa per svelarne l’interno.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "indentatura" in alcuni dizionari. Tuttavia, le definizioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere molto senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa questo termine nel brano sopra citato?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credo che in questo contesto il significato di indentatura sia da intendere come sinonimo di incastro, ovvero il collegamento meccanico che rende le cose solidali tra loro.
L'indentatura salta, e dunque le cose che sono state unite artificialmente si separano.
Si tratta ovviamente di una metafora, o di una immagine onirica, come, in un crescendo, le crepe nell'intonaco che si aprono, o le ossa del cranio che si separano, o addirittura il bambino che si rompe.

Answer (score 0):

CasaMich ha dato una buona risposta.

Un'altra possibile interpretazione viene dal fatto che, in programmazione informatica, il codice viene "indentato" (formattato con spaziature) per renderlo più leggibile ed ordinato.

Questa pratica è così importante che, di fatto, il codice non indentato viene considerato inusabile/illeggibile (v. qualsiasi domanda posta da utenti novizi su StackOverflow, il sito principale di StackExchange).

In altre parole, l'indentatura può essere letta come "l'ordine fondamentale delle cose", che i battiti forti ed incessanti del cuore spazzano via, lasciando solo il caos.

Comment: Bisognerebbe sapere quanto ne sa la Ferrante di convenzioni informatiche. D'altronde, misteriosa com'è, magari è Knuth e non lo sa nessuno.

Comment: @DaG Il termine è usato in informatica ma ha origini in tipografia, con la stessa nozione. Direi che è probabile che ne sia a conoscenza :)

Comment: Ma “indentare” e derivati sono calchi dall'inglese entrati in italiano in tempi recenti con questo significato, tanto è vero che per “indentare” e “indentazione” non riportano questi significati né il Treccani né lo Zingarelli (che pure in genere è più aperto a neologismi e nuove accezioni). Che io sappia, in tipografia si parla di “rientranza”.

Comment: Hai ragione. Magari sono fuori strada.

Comment: In tipografia e in programmazione ho sentito parlare più spesso di indentazione che di indentatura.

Comment: @CasaMich sono la stessa cosa a quanto ne so io

Answer (score 0):

Per "indentatura" si intende pure, nella meccanica e nell'edilizia, uno spazio creato con la finalità di accogliere un elemento portante, fisso, che possa sopportare un carico o delimitare un perimetro. Nel contesto specifico, credo possa essere interpretato come "il giusto ordine delle cose", che prevede spazi riempiti e spazi lasciati vuoti. In particolare, il vuoto - in tale contesto - assume senso proprio perché permette di dare un significato allo spazio che invece è pieno. Ovvero non c'è pieno senza vuoto e viceversa, nella collocazione delle cose.